# mysql - correct approach to relate these tables

Tags: mysql

So, I have 2 tables

On the first table, lets call it products, lets say I have

```
product_id, company_id (this is a FK), product_name.
```

On the second table, lets call it deals, I have

```
deal_id, company_id (same one as the first table), deal_title.
```

I need to add products to the deals. if I added a product_id field to the deals table, I would have multiple rows and ids for each deal, which is completely wrong. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Thanks for revising it, I'm still not very familiar with stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a  table for manage the relation between products and deals
eg:

```
 table products_deal 

 product_id 
 deal_id
```

Comment: So this table would not have a primary key,  only those 2 ids so I can relate them,  correct?

Comment: In the previous  i have posted  only the conceptual contest .. you can  add an id or use the (product_id, deal_id)  like a unique key  .. but this application dependent i don't know if the couple is unque cor not .. if unique  then you don't need id otherwise .. add the id  ..

Comment: @Lberteh those two fields would be the primary key (unless a deal can have a product multiple times for some reason); or if you need to reference these rows elsewhere a single id might be desired.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) between the two tables you have that have a structure like:

```
|-deal_id----|-product_id----|
| 10         | 23            |
| 10         | 24            |
| 10         | 32            |
| ...
| ...
```

If you need to find all products associated with deal #10, you can just use a query like `SELECT * FROM pivot_table WHERE deal_id = 10`